# Error during restart /etc/network/interface file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I manually changed in /etc/network/interface file eth0 configuration, but when i tried to make changes by using "ifdown" and "ifup" i get error like below:

```
# /sbin/ifdown -a
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
ifdown: interface can0 not configured
ifdown: interface can1 not configured
ifdown: interface can2 not configured
ifdown: interface usb0 not configured
# /sbin/ifup -a
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Cannot find device "can0"
Cannot find device "can1"
Cannot find device "can2"
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

Which could be the reason? I cant use ifconfig. Struct of file should be correct.

Comment: Is eth0 actually a named interface?

Comment: just like below:

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.10.190
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.10.1